# How to build SignalR hub and hub calls within a website?

Tags: c#, azure, blazor, signalr, signalr.client

I have a website that uses blazor pages. I am trying to implement SignalR within these pages. Currently, when a form is submitted or action is performed, an api call is sent. I want to use SignalR. Is it good practice to relocate the api calls from within my 'HandleValidSubmit' method to within the part to register endpoints in SignalR. Also I apologize for my formatting

For example.

```
private async void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        formValidation?.ClearErrors();
        var response = await HttpGateway.PostAsync(NavigationManager.BaseUri, "my uri", content);
        
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            //webpage redirect
        }
        else
        {
            //displays errors
        }
    }
```

to

```
        hubConnection?.On("request", async (var content) => 
            {
                var response = await HttpGateway.PostAsync(NavigationManager.BaseUri, "my uri", content);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            //webpage redirect
        }
        else
        {
            //displays errors
        }
            }
        );


private async void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        formValidation?.ClearErrors();
        hubConnection.SendAsync("request");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Following these steps will help you build a SignalR hub and hub calls within a website:

1. Install SignalR: Use NuGet to install the SignalR package in your web project.
2. Create a SignalR Hub Class: Create a SignalR hub class that will handle incoming client requests.
3. Define Hub Methods: Define hub methods in your hub class for handling client requests.
4. Add SignalR Client Code: Implement the SignalR client code in your website to send data to the hub or invoke hub methods.
5. Start the SignalR Hub: Start the SignalR hub by calling the “MapSignalR” method in the web application’s “Startup” class.
6. Test SignalR Connections: Test the SignalR connections by invoking hub methods from the client and receiving data from the hub.

Comment: Should I put my API requests that perform external actions within the hub methods?

Comment: hmm,
well.....In general, it is not recommended to perform API requests that perform external actions directly within SignalR hub methods. The primary reason is that SignalR hubs are designed to handle real-time communication between clients and the server, focusing on broadcasting messages and maintaining connections. Performing external actions within hub methods can introduce potential issues and impact the responsiveness of the real-time communication.

Instead, it is recommended to separate the concerns and decouple the API requests from the SignalR hub methods

Comment: did you use chatgpt or any other AI at all to write any part of this answer?